# Image processing by CUDA

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, cuda

I used openCV functions and variables in a cuda file.but I got these errors:

1. 19  IntelliSense: this declaration has no storage class or type
   specifier
2. no instance of overloaded function "cudaMalloc" matches the argument
   list
3. 6   IntelliSense: expected a ';'
4. 13  IntelliSense: identifier "dim3" is undefined

here is my code

```
#include <cxcore.h>
#include <highgui.h>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include "cuda.h" 
#include <tchar.h>
#include <cv.h>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

__global__ void kernel( void ) { 
}
int main( void ) 
{
Mat originalImage;     
originalImage = imread("C:\\lena.bmp",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);   


/// show original image
namedWindow("Original");
int x = 0; int y = 0;
moveWindow("Original",x,y);
imshow("Original", originalImage);

Mat dctImage = originalImage.clone();
dctImage.convertTo(dctImage,CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
originalImage.convertTo(originalImage,CV_32FC1, 1.0/255.0);
Mat tmp1(512, 512, CV_32FC1);
resize(originalImage, originalImage, tmp1.size());
resize(dctImage, dctImage, tmp1.size());

cout<<dctImage.type()<<endl;
cout<<wmrk.size()<<endl;
////declare device variable    
float *dctImage_dev , *wmrk_dev;

dim3 blocks(64,64);
dim3 threads(8,8);

/////allocate memory on device
//cudaMalloc( (void**)dctImage_dev, dctImage.size() ) ;

/////launch kernel
kernel<<<1,1>>>();
printf( "Hello, World!\n" );

cvWaitKey(80000);

return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My first suggestion is to move the cuda code into a different file, so you have a standard compiler do the opencv + program flow and let the `cuda c++` compiler do the actual cuda code because `cuda c++` is NOT `c++` ! And you should expect standard compilers like gcc or msvc to do better than cuda c++ in non-gpu modules. There are plenty of tutorials out there that explain how to set up different compilers for different files in your project, including specific tutorials by nvidia.

As to the specific error you have, dctImage.size() returns an object of type `Mat::Size`, which is not implicitly conversible to `size_t` (size_t in this context means **number of bytes)**. The following methods can be useful for you to determine the Mat's buffer size, but you can look up the following Mat members [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#mat): Mat::elemSize, Mat::step, Mat::step1(), Mat::cols,Mat::rows,Mat::channels(). It is a trivial multiplication task when you get familiar with the API.